# How to configure .htaccess file in WAMPServer?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp

I am using WAMPServer as developping locally. I have a problem in redirecting pages with `.htaccess`

my `.htaccess` file is in root folder.

I have decommented the

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

`rewrite_module` is enabled in apache.

But it still does not work.

Note: it works in **MAMP** server as I checked but not in **WAMP**.

here is my `.htaccess` file.

```
# I tried both below solutions which found on internet but none of them worked
# - Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# - Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home$ /SiteTemplate/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^users$ /SiteTemplate/users.php [L]
RewriteRule ^addUser$ /SiteTemplate/registration.php [L]
```

in may httpd.conf it's like this.

```
# <Directory />
    # AllowOverride none
    # Require all denied
# </Directory>

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Anybody can help please ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not work for us, as a problem description. Explain what _exactly_ happens. And give a proper example of what exact URL you are requesting to begin with.

Comment: Well commenting this code `# <Directory /> # AllowOverride none  # Require all denied
# </Directory>` say hacker come on in, my PC is yours. You have to CHECK stuff you find on the internet against a good read of the Apache or relevant manual. Otherwise you will be giving away the crown jewels

Comment: And adding `<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>` Makes it a hackers paradise